# StaleDataError sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

```
@app.route('/create_playlist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_playlist():
  songs = Song.query.all()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    playlist_name = request.form.get('playlist_name')
    if not playlist_name:
      return render_template('create_playlist.html', error="Playlist name is required.", songs=songs)
    selected_song_ids = request.form.getlist('selected_songs')
    if len(selected_song_ids) == 0:
      return render_template('create_playlist.html', error="Please select at least one song for the playlist.", songs=songs)
    playlist = Playlist(name=playlist_name, user_id=current_user.id)
    for song_id in selected_song_ids:
      song = Song.query.get(song_id)
      playlist.associated_songs.append(song)
    db.session.add(playlist)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('user_homepage'))
  return render_template('create_playlist.html', songs=songs)
```

THIS IS MY CREATE PLAYLIST ROUTE

```
@app.route('/delete_playlist/<int:playlist_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_playlist(playlist_id):
  """Deletes a playlist by its ID."""
  playlist = Playlist.query.get(playlist_id)
  if not playlist or playlist.user_id != current_user.id:
    flash('Invalid playlist or access denied.', 'error')
    return redirect(url_for('user_homepage'))
  playlist.associated_songs.clear()
  db.session.delete(playlist)
  db.session.commit()
  flash('Playlist deleted successfully.', 'success')
  return redirect(url_for('user_homepage'))
```

THIS IS MY DELETE PLAYLIST ROUTE

```
class Song(db.Model): tablename = "songs"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
filename = db.Column(db.String(255))
title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
artist = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
lyrics = db.Column(db.Text)
album = db.Column(db.String(255))
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
playlists_association = db.relationship(
    "Playlist",
    secondary="playlist_song_association",
    back_populates="associated_songs"
)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"<Song {self.filename}>"

class Playlist(db.Model): tablename = "playlists"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)

songs = db.relationship(
    "Song",
    secondary="playlist_song_association",
    back_populates="playlists_association",
)

associated_songs = db.relationship(
    "Song",
    secondary="playlist_song_association",
    back_populates="playlists_association",
)

playlist_song_association = db.Table(
    'playlist_song_association',
    db.Column('playlist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('playlists.id')),
    db.Column('song_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('songs.id'))
)
```

THIS IS HOW MY CLASSES ARE DEFINED AND HOW A RELATIONSHIP B/W SONG & PLAYLIST IS ESTABLISHED

After trying to delte a playist, I get the following error:
StaleDataError
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'playlist_song_association' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 290, in decorated_view
    return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\music_app\app.py", line 204, in delete_playlist
    db.session.commit()
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 598, in commit
    return self._proxied.commit()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1969, in commit
    trans.commit(_to_root=True)
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1256, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "<string>", line 2, in _prepare_impl
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1231, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 4312, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 4447, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 4408, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 466, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    self.dependency_processor.process_deletes(uow, states)
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\dependency.py", line 1118, in process_deletes
    self._run_crud(
  File "C:\Users\pajas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\dependency.py", line 1220, in _run_crud
    raise exc.StaleDataError(
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'playlist_song_association' expected to delete 1 row(s); Only 2 were matched.
```

Then looking around, I found out that it might be happening because of duplicate entries and when I looked at the table, that was indeed the issue.
I don't know why adding a song creates 2 identical entries in the playlist_song_association table.

Comment: The problem is that the `songs` and `associated_songs` relationships defined on `PlayList`; they are effectively the same, why are there two? Also, what is the purpose of calling `playlist.associated_songs.clear()` in  `delete_playlist` ?